# Vuetify - how to check if printing

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have a page that I also want to style for printing. However some classes I only want to apply when on screen but not on print.

Thus wondering how I can apply those classes only in these cases. With styles I can use `@media print {...}` but with classed I don't know.

Is there a better way then duplicating the structure and applying different styles there?

Cheers
Tom